# Mendeley doesn't start

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, mendeley

I have installed Mendenley (32 bits) on a fresh Ubuntu Mate 18.04.5 LTS 32 bits, when I try to launch it by this command `mendeleydesktop` , it shows me the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/mendeleydesktop: error while loading shared libraries:
    libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: The answer, for your question is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/978294/how-to-fix-libpng12-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-direc

Comment: @mariaczi, thank you. It's for 64 bits system

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problems related to the missing "libpng12.0" file are common in some Ubuntu distros.
It has been solved simply as follow:

1. Download "libpng12.0" file from [this link](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/15108507) (i.e, libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb),
2. Install it: `sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb`

and finally Mendeley launched successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue (Ubuntu 22.04). I also have a Nvidia GPU card. Installing libpng did not work for me. Changing the driver (to 510) did not solve my issue. I found this solution (install Mendeley via flatpak) that worked (be sure to completely remove the previous version of Mendeley!):

$ sudo flatpak install flathub com.elsevier.MendeleyDesktop

$ flatpak run com.elsevier.MendeleyDesktop